# Clean way for a component to support both React 17 and React 18

Tags: reactjs

React 18 introduced a new way to manually render a component, now instead of calling

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
ReactDOM.render(component, container)
```

one must call

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
createRoot(container).render(component);
```

Failure to do so results in a warning to the console and reverting back to React 17 API compatibility.

Is there an official or at least a semi-clean way for a component published to NPM to support both APIs?

There is `React.version` that I can check.

However `createRoot` is in a separate file, this means I am looking at a conditional import that will surely be source of problems with the various bundlers and transpilers.

Any better ideas?

*Note: The component in question is https://www.npmjs.com/package/rlayers which includes a virtual component, the map style, with a `render()` property, that can be rendered off-screen to compute the map style. Any answer that allows me to call all the nested `render()` methods while providing a value for a context is also a valid one.*

Comment: Does the npm package really include not only the component, but also the call to render/createRoot? If so, that's rather unusual. Most npm packages relating to react will just contain the components, and it's up to the app that uses those components to call render/createRoot

Comment: Yes, it does, it is https://www.npmjs.com/package/rlayers for rendering maps - it includes a virtual component - the map style - that it is rendered off-screen - to compute the map style

Comment: try createProtal instead?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a good way.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
let createRoot: unknown;
try {
  createRoot = require('react-dom/client').createRoot;
} catch (e) {
  // stuff 
}

/**
 * react16 and react18 compatible render function
 * @param {*} element react element
 * @param {*} container dom element
 * @return unmount function
 */
export function render(
  element: React.ReactElement,
  container: Element,
): () => void {
  if (typeof createRoot === 'function') {
    const root = createRoot(container).render(element);
    return () => {
      if (root) {
        root.unmount();
      }
    };
  }
  ReactDOM.render(element, container);
  return () => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);
  };
}
```

using async import is also a choice.